# Setting card owner 2.0p5

Tags: rally

I am updating my custom kanban boards, and running into an issue with the newer API.  This worked in 2.0p2, but not working in 5.

I have some code that is trying to set the current card to the current user.  This is on the method beforecarddroppedsave.

card.record.set('Owner', con.context.user);

I can set other fields, that seems ok, but when trying to save the User, it isnt working.  I have tried just setting the name to the owner, and that doesnt work either.

I looked in the documentation, but cant seem to find it yet, any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the current App SDK 2.0rc1. This code should set the Owner on the card when the car is moved from one column to another:

```
 var cardBoardConfig = {
                        xtype: 'rallycardboard',
                        types: ['Defect', 'User Story'],
                        attribute: 'ScheduleState',
                        storeConfig: {
                            filters: [this.iterationCombobox.getQueryFromSelected()]
                        },
            listeners: {
                      beforecarddroppedsave: this._onMove,
                                  scope: this
                }
                    };
//..........
    _onMove: function(cardboard, card){
            var con = Rally.environment.getContext();
                card.record.set('Owner', con.context.user);
            console.log('ok');
        },
```